# How to add sub choices in a Sharepoint 2010 survey

Tags: survey

Is there a way to do it. e.g.

- 1st Jan

  - 8am - 9am
  - 9am - 10am
- 3rd Jan

  - 8am - 9am
  - 9am - 10am

So users can select either 1st Jan or 3rd Jan and then select the timings within. 
Please do not take this question down even though I accept it is a repeat (https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/57580/how-to-create-a-survey-in-sharepoint-which-supports-sub-options-in-choice-item). No answers/comments were given on that question but I hope this post is replied to even in the negative.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Branching logic in survey question?

You can create separate Questions for Date and Time. Based on user's selection of date, you can redirect the user to appropriate next question (timeslots available for that particular date)

Ref: https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-in/article/Add-branching-logic-to-a-survey-e100ebcf-2155-4cea-b068-647fb5ca785e?CorrelationId=84c01b41-c99b-491c-8838-8a5bf9f89174&ui=en-US&rs=en-IN&ad=IN#bm2

Answer (score 0):

to achive this you can create a cusom SharePoint field. In this field you will be able to manage everything from display to rendering.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg132913.aspx) post how it can be done.

There are different methodes to use. E.g. you can override render HTML method to render you html as you wish.

Hope it helps,

Andrew